# OracleClient works with WPF application but not web application

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, oracleclient

I am porting a WPF application to a web application (ASP.net & C#).  My IDE is Visual Studio 2008 and we are using Oracle 11g.  My OS is Windows 7 , 64-bit. THe WPF application uses System.Data.OracleClient to connect to our database and it works fine.  I added the OracleClient reference to the workspace and tried using the same namespace in the ASP.Net application but I get an error when trying to connect to the database (.Open()).  The error is:

"Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

I checked the configuration manager in the WPF application and the web app.  They are set the same:
Platform - AnyCPU

I tried using the 64-bit version of Oracle Client and it still gives me the same error.
I did this by removing the reference to System.Data.OracleClient located in Windows/Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 and added the reference to the 64-bit version in Windows/Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks